# Angular: Issue with Model Instance Check in Component Inheritance

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I am currently encountering an issue with Angular components and inheritance. I have a base component named `BaseRegistrationModelComponent` that handles common functionalities for registration forms, and I am extending this base component in my `ProductRegistrationComponent`.

In the `submitForm` method of ProductRegistrationComponent, attempting to verify whether `super.model` is an instance of `Product`. Strangely, even though I initialize super.model as an empty instance of `Product`, it consistently enters the else block and outputs:

*Error: this.model is not an instance of Product*

ProductRegistrationScreenComponent

```
export class ProductRegistrationScreenComponent { 
  
  @ViewChild(ProductRegistrationComponent) productRegistration!: ProductRegistrationComponent;      
}
```

ProductRegistrationComponent

```
export class ProductRegistrationComponent extends BaseRegistrationModelComponent<Product>{

    constructor(crudService: CrudService<Product>, configService: ProductConfigService) 
    {
      super(crudService, configService);
    }
    
    override submitForm() {         

      /* Just a test: Is this.model instance of Product once I initialize BaseRegistrationModelComponent
      with Product? */

      if (this.model instanceof Product) {
        console.info('this.model is an instance of Product.');
      }
      else{
        console.error('Error: this.model is not an instance of Product.');
      }

      super.model.purchasePrice = parseFloat(super.model.purchasePrice.toString().replace('R$ ', '').replace(',', '.'));

      super.crudService.create(super.model).subscribe(() => {
        super.model = super.createEmptyInstance();        
        super.loadProducts();
      });
    }
  }
```

BaseRegistrationModelComponent

```
@Injectable()
export class BaseRegistrationModelComponent <T extends Persistable>{

  model: T = this.createEmptyInstance();
  modelList: T[] = [];
  registrationCompleted: boolean = false;
  commonUtils: any;

  constructor(
    public crudService: CrudService<T>,  public configService: ConfigService
  ) {
    this.crudService.setConfigService(this.configService);
    this.loadProducts();
  }

  public createEmptyInstance(): T {
    return {} as T;
  }  

  loadProducts() {
    this.crudService.getAll().subscribe((products) => {
      this.modelList = products;
    });
  }

  submitForm() 
  {
    this.crudService.create(this.model).subscribe(() => {
      this.model = this.createEmptyInstance();
      this.loadProducts();
    });
  }  
}
```

Comment: Did you print this.model to see what is it if not a Product ?

Comment: @skuti It was a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `this` instead of `super` to access the `model` and other members. The `super` reserved keyword is typically used within a constructor to call the constructor of the superclass, or to access overrides methods in the superclass. That said, you should use `this` keyword to access properties and methods defined in the current class or any defined superclasses.

Here the code with the modifications:

```
export class ProductRegistrationComponent extends BaseRegistrationModelComponent<Product>{

  constructor(crudService: CrudService<Product>, configService: ProductConfigService) 
  {
    super(crudService, configService);
    this.model = new Product();
  }

  override submitForm() {         
    if (this.model instanceof Product) {
      console.info('this.model is an instance of Product.');
    }
    else{
      console.error('Error: this.model is not an instance of Product.');
    }

    this.model.purchasePrice = parseFloat(this.model.purchasePrice.toString().replace('R$ ', '').replace(',', '.'));

    this.crudService.create(this.model).subscribe(() => {
      this.model = this.createEmptyInstance();        
      this.loadProducts();
    });
  }

  override createEmptyInstance(): Product {
    return new Product();
  }
}
```

and also, the `createEmptyInstance` function from `BaseRegistrationModelComponent` was overridden in `ProductRegistrationComponent` to return a `Product` instance instead of an empty object:

```
override createEmptyInstance(): Product {
    return new Product();
}
```